# Heroku app cannot connect to Celery worker

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I have created a `Django` app which is using `Celery` for task processing. It’s working fine locally but when I pushed it to `Heroku`, I found that app cannot connect to Celery worker.

I can see worker is running without any problem.

```
$ heroku ps

=== web (Free): gunicorn my_django_project.wsgi --log-file - (1)
web.1: up 2019/08/10 11:54:19 +0530 (~ 1m ago)

=== worker (Free): celery -A my_django_project worker -l info (1)
worker.1: up 2019/08/10 11:54:19 +0530 (~ 1m ago)
```

But when I checked the logs I found this error message

```
2019-08-10T06:04:30.402781+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2019-08-10 06:04:30,402: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
2019-08-10T06:04:30.402801+00:00 app[worker.1]: Trying again in 32.00 seconds...
```

Seems like app cannot connect to celery worker.

**Project directory structure**

```
Project
|
├── data/
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── my_app/
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── my_django_project/
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── runtime.txt
└── static/
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn my_django_project.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A my_django_project worker -l info
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

#set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', my_django_project.settings')

app = Celery(my_django_project)

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def task1():

   // do stuff

    return results
```

[image]

Comment: Have you setup the rabbitmq backend that the celery worker needs?
Check it in your `celery.py` file with something like: `app = Celery("my_django_project", broker=settings.BROKER_URL, backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)
print(f'connected to celery using broker: {settings.BROKER_URL} and backend: {settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND}')`

Comment: @cs_stackX Hello, So I need to change Line-8 in celery.py with what you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672` Refers to the backend celery tries to use, you need to setup a backend either rabbitMQ, Redis or something else.

[The docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#choosing-a-broker)

Comment: I am using CloudAMQP (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudamqp) at the backend, I have set CLOUDAMQP_URL from Heroku in settings.py, do I have configure some other things.

Comment: The result backend and broker urls should both point to your heroku amqp

Answer (score 0):

Celery requires a solution to send and receive messages; usually this comes in the form of a separate service called a message broker.

You can choose

- RabbitMQ
- Redis
- Amazon SQS (experimental)

You can test this locally before setting up in Heroku by specifying a broker in your celery config, e.g.: `app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')`

For this to work, you will need to have already started up your broker locally.

For redis that would be with:
`pip install -U "celery[redis]"`
then set the broker url to the location of the redis database (default 'redis://localhost:6379/0') the url follows this format: redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number

- then run `redis-server`
- then run your celery worker
- then start your django app

Once you're comfortable with all that, use the Heroku add ons to select your broker of choice (there are many options, e.g. Redis Cloud). Then update your environment variables to use the add-on backend url in your heroku environment vars. This will be of a format like: `redis://p%40ssw0rd@redis-16379.someservice.com:PORT_NUMBER/0`